# How can I bundle my database file into my app, ready for a side load install?

Tags: win-universal-app

I am creating a Windows 10 Universal App which uses a local SQLite Database.
In order for the app to use the database file It must be placed in:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<Name of Package>\Local State
```

Now I understand this is the 'local' file structure for the application. However I have a pre-made database that the app needs to interact with and therefore should be bundled as part of the app on install.

Is there a method of including my database in a usable fashion when distributing my application via a side-load install?

Furthermore, This problem is of paramount importance as This 'C:\' Directory will not exist when pushing my application to the mobile phone or other Windows 10 (not a desktop) device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot package the database directly as read-write data (local state). If you only ever need to read from the database, you can just include it in your project and read it from [`Package.Current.InstalledLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx).

If you need to write to the database, but it contains some initial values you want to ship with your app, then you still need to include the database in your project, but then copy it from the `InstalledLocation` to [`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) if it doesn't exist when your app starts up.

Answer (score 3):

You can all ways export your existing data base as SQL script and save it in your project assets. 
On the first run of your application you can create the Sqlite file in your LocalFolder, and run the script with CREATE and INSERT queries.

Comment: This is also a very valid option